# Javascript/Jquery - Get the width of many blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My English is not good. So I will try to use the picture in question.

I have a responsive web form with multiple `A block`s (fixed width 180px) arranged in consecutive order. It is based on the width of the `CONTENT block` (width of CONTENT is not fixed). And `B block` will be as wide as the width of many `A block`.
[image]

My old solution is to create a `C block`. Then take the width of `C block` and assign that width to `B block`. But the problem is that `C block` will suffer from the limitations of the css. chỉ có cách sử dụng display:inline mới có thể biết được chiều rộng của "C block". Only using display: inline can know the width of `C block`. That makes `C` not cover all blocks
[image: old solution][image]

EX: https://jsfiddle.net/bindo1995/L5m09f3q/4/

Now, another solution is to take the width of the `CONTENT block` and divide it by 180 (px). Then take the number to the left of decimal, and multiply by 180 (px), the width of `B block` will be output without the accounting for the `C block`.
[image]

EX: https://jsfiddle.net/bindo1995/L5m09f3q/3/

I need a script code to solve the new solution. I just started with this script. There are many things I do not know yet. Please help me answer the above question. I will be very thankful!

Comment: just an interesting point. should check out [css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: With the margin, I don't think block C is exactly 540px.

Comment: @Christoph I need a script code in the new solution

Comment: @RichardYan For example, it is easier to understand. Block A has other <div> tags

Comment: @Sarfaraaz "B block" is a tag outside "Content block". So if you use only Css, "B block" will not change based on "A block"

Comment: @LeTung if they share a common class that defines their width it could but not with flexbox, so I get you... wow this question has changed a bit since i made that comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
 var width=$(".content").width();
  var num = Math.floor(width/180);
 $(".b").css('width',num*180).text(num*180);
  $(window).resize(function() { 
 var width=$(".content").width();
  var num = Math.floor(width/180);
 $(".b").css('width',num*180).text(num*180);
 }); 
});
```

But why if I shorten the code as below, it causes the browser to crash

```
$( document ).ready(function abc() { 
 var width=$(".content").width();
  var num = Math.floor(width/180);
 $(".b").css('width',num*180).text(num*180);
  $(window).resize(function() { 
 abc();
 }); 
});
```

Comment: It's because you are calling function abc on window resize which resizes the window. *it's an infinite loop*. you should make that a separate question normally btw